# conda activated via pyton shell script doesn't run with imports

Tags: python, shell, conda

I am trying to use a python script to run another python project which needs some specific conda environment settings. I am using the code below to do that, but everytime I run this, it outputs **ImportErrors** and it seems that it is not using any of the modules that my conda environment has already installed

```py
import os

os.system('source ~/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh; conda activate tf-2; python demo.py --image /Users/mingaioh/Desktop/car.png')
```

Comment: Could you post the complete error message in your question? Does the same thing happen if you put `os.system('conda run -n tf -2 python demo.py --image /Users/mingaioh/Desktop/car.png')` in your script instead of the line you had?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help... try `python3 -m pip install os` or `python -m pip install os`

Comment: `os` is a built in module and cannot be installed through pip